# Angular JS - Array.splice() causes undefined items

Tags: javascript, angularjs, array-splice

Good day!

I'm currently working on manipulating my Array by adding objects at index 0 using the push method and removing items using the splice method. As I've read and understood, when you splice an item from an array, it does not leave the array with 'undefined' item. The problem is, I'm currently getting an 'undefined' item when using my splice.

Here  is my code for adding entries:

```
addOrRemoveRating(0,0,{
    rating : 0,
    tran_number : transaction_number,
    email : $scope.called_numbers[0].email
});
```

Here is my code for removing entries:

```
 addOrRemoveRating(array_index,1);
```

on which the array_index is an existing index.

And the last part is where the splicing occurs:

```
addOrRemoveRating = function(index, item, object){
    $scope.temp_called_numbers.splice(index, item, object);
}
```

For example, I have 3 objects in my array- [Object, Object, Object], after deleting the item, it returns - [Object, Object, undefined].

Is there anything I'm missing or wrong with the code? Any help, reference or coaching is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you only call your function with two arguments, `object` will be `undefined`, therefore, `undefined` will added to the array.

Try this instead

```
$scope.temp_called_numbers.splice.apply($scope.temp_called_numbers, arguments);
```

<kbd>[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jcm64nrt/1/)</kbd>

Using this, you can take advantage of the varargs nature of `Array.prototype.splice` and pass multiple objects to add to the array.

Comment: Thanks, will try this and check which is more efficient.

Comment: Thanks Phil. Your explanation helped me, but I'm gonna follow Brent's suggestion for simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an AngularJS issue, it's strictly Javascript.  Calling `splice()` with three parameters will splice the third parameter in at the specified location.  If you leave off the third parameter (`object`), it will simply delete the objects from the array.

```
addOrRemoveRating = function(index, item, object){
    if (object)
        $scope.temp_called_numbers.splice(index, item, object);
    else
        $scope.temp_called_numbers.splice(index, item);
}
```

Comment: Apologies, I really thought this was an angular issue because lately I've been experiencing a lot of JQuery-Angular issues. I'm still learning the Angular.

I will test this.

Comment: I see this happening even when I don't specify the 3rd parameter